# Writing to a text file in Visual Basic stops at 3074 bytes. Any idea why?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have developed a small program using Visual Basic Express 2010 that reads a file, scans it line by line, when the line contains some specific text, it manipulates the text and writes that manipulated text to a new file, if that condition is not met, it writes the original line.

It is working ok, gives no errors and completes the run. However, it stops writing to the file at some point. I have checked the files and the only common thing I find between the several tests is that the new files all have 3074 bytes as size. Is this a limitation of VB Express? Am I using the wrong way of writing to the file?

Here a reduced version of the code:

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Linha As String
        Dim datapag As String

        'Open File
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim novoficheiro As New System.IO.StreamWriter(OpenFileDialog1.FileName + "2.xml")

            Dim Ficheiro As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

            'Scan lines one at a time
            Do While Ficheiro.Peek <> -1
                Linha = Ficheiro.ReadLine
                Dim tratada As Boolean
                tratada = False


                'Make some changes in specific conditions
                If Linha.Contains("<PaymentDueDate>") Then
                    datapag = Mid(Linha, 17, 8)
                    Dim composta, Novalinha3 As String
                    composta = Mid(datapag, 1, 4) + "-"
                    composta = composta + Mid(datapag, 5, 2) + "-"
                    composta = composta + Mid(datapag, 7, 2)
                    Novalinha3 = Replace(Linha, datapag, composta)


                    novoficheiro.WriteLine(Novalinha3)

                    tratada = True
                End If

                'If no changes were made write the original line
                If tratada = False Then
                    novoficheiro.WriteLine(Linha)
                End If

            Loop

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

So, the idea is that I have a new version of the file with just some lines changed.
I have added messages throughout the code to show me the contents of the lines sent to the new file and they are all parsed ok, corrected correctly when needed and unchanged when no correction is necessary.
The file just gets truncated at some point, depending on how many different conditions I handle but always resulting in a file with 3074 byte size (the original file is 2787 bytes long, BTW).

Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to flush and close the StreamWriter after your done writing the file and before you exit the function.  After the Loop and before the End If, add the line:

```
novoficheiro.Close()
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, mate! Worked like a charm. Would anyone care to explain what's behind this? I expect it has something to do with buffering and the way bytes are sent to the file... I'll look into documentation to try and find out but it could be interesting to other readers before I get around to that.

Comment: Yes, it is buffering and only writing out in chunks.  If you exit the function and the StreamWriter is disposed, then anything still in the buffer and not written to disk, will then be lost and the file will be incomplete.  I believe there are ways to alter this behavior but I'm not sure off the top of my head how.